# Get rid of custom menu items from UIMenuController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uimenucontroller

I am using `UITableViewController`. If I long press on a `tableview cell` I am creating custom menus in the `UIMenuController` and which is working fine (Forward, Reply). In the same view I have the `textview` in the bottom. If I tap on it should display the normal actions but it doesn't. It comes with default items as well as what are the items I have added for the `tableview cell` (Forward, Reply). How to remove the custom items from the `UIMenuController` or how to perform the action for a particular cell.

Inside the cell I have an `UIImageView`. I have added gestures to perform the action.

Comment: are you able to hide the default items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have implemented `canPerformAction:withSender:` to get your custom items to work. In that method you can verify the sender to check what class / instance it is and decide what to do.

Alternatively, check which instance is the first responder.

Comment: How were you able to get which instance this method is being called on?

Answer (score 2):

For this, first you create a menu with custom items and then listen to `UIMenuControllerWillHideMenuNotification` notification. In side this notification when menu is going to hide you can remove the items what you added. Here is the sample code.

```
-(void) showMenu{
     UIMenuController * menuController =[UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
     UIMenuItem * item1 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Goto" action:@selector(menuItem1Clicked:)];
     UIMenuItem * item2 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" action:@selector(menuItem2Clicked:)];
     [menuController setMenuItems:@[item, item1]];
     [menuController setTargetRect:rect inView:self.view];
     [menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
}
```

And when menu is going to hide remove the items you added

```
-(void) menuControllerWillHide:(NSNotification*)notification
{
     UIMenuController * controller = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
     NSArray * items = [controller menuItems]; // These are all custom items you added
     NSMutableArray * finalItemsYouWant = [NSMutableArray array];
     // Here you can check what items you dont want and then remove it
     [controller setMenuItems:finalItemsYouWant];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift3: 
in viewDidLoad of ViewController:

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(menuControllerWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIMenuControllerWillHideMenu, object: nil)

func menuControllerWillHide(notification:NSNotification){
    UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = []
}
```

Comment: that's what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)showMenu:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)longPressRecognizer  
{  
    longPressRowNum = longPressRecognizer.view.tag;  
    NSIndexPath *indPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:longPressRecognizer.view.tag inSection:0];
    //Type cast it to CustomCell   
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[projectTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indPath];        
    ProjectDashBoard *projectDashBoard = [listRecord objectAtIndex:longPressRecognizer.view.tag];
    NSLog(@"long press project status---%@",projectDashBoard.projectStatus);

    if (longPressRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {



    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = (UITableViewCell *)longPressRecognizer.view;
    [selectedCell setSelected:YES];

    UIMenuItem *delete = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"deleteproject", nil)  action:@selector(deleteClicked:)];

    UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];

    if([projectDashBoard.projectStatus isEqualToString:statusActive]){
        UIMenuItem *archive = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"archiveproject", nil)  action:@selector(archiveClicked:)];
        [menu setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:delete, archive, nil]];
    }else{
        UIMenuItem *archive = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"unarchiveproject", nil)  action:@selector(archiveClicked:)];
        [menu setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:delete, archive, nil]];
    }

    [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] update];
    [menu setTargetRect:cell.frame inView:cell.superview];
    [menu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
 }
}
```